# silverlight 3 Datagrid header customization

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I am working on silverlight3 toolkit controls. I have to add listbox control in column header of datagrid.

For example, I have a `dept` column in datagrid control. When I mouse over on dept column header, it has to show list of dept names and Depend on listbox selected item, I have to filter my datagrid items.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this item.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/autofiltering_silverlight.aspx solves your problem... or helps to solve.